# how to solve webfont problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, webfonts

I am using Bootstrap.css and font-awesome.css in my project with cdn links.
Eg:
   For bootstrp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and for font-awesome

```
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In my code i use class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" etc. its working fine.
but when I download the css files from the same links resp. and add dependencies locally its not running. error says

```
 GET http://localhost:8451/ProntoDemo/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 
 GET http://localhost:8451/ProntoDemo/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't understand what the problem is. please help me to run locally.
like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: can you show exactly how you are modifying you `css`

Comment: You get a 404 error - file not found. Check your logs to see what filepath your url resolves to.

Comment: i create bootstrp.min.css file in my project dir and add thet to my html page.

Answer (score 2):

Since font files comes with bundle ,they are having ttf(true type font) files which contains fonts. so you need to download the zip and extract to your server then only you can link the css file ..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Fonts/font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

LINK  https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: extract to your server means extract and copy the file in the project directory of the IDE??

Comment: yes @Subho ,to your server means extract and copy the file in the project directory of the IDE

Comment: Thank You @Rohit for ur support. But I got another solution for my problem. In downloaded bootstrap.css there is src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot').. But in my project directory I create font not fonts. i just change that. same for font-awesome.